# How can I show data on graph in real-time?

Tags: taipy

I want to show a graph with data that I receive in real-time so I want the graph to be updated, it is ok for me that the update frequency is every 2 seconds.
I don't want to have an external event like a button.

I tried to run a thread that will change the graph data but the graph (and a map) are refreshing all the time so it is not elegant to view:

```
from taipy.gui import Gui, notify
import threading
import time

text = "Original text"

list_to_display = [100/x for x in range(1, 100)]
list_to_display_1 = list_to_display
is_first_time = True


data = {"x_col":[0,1,2], "y_col1":[4,1,2]}

# Flight start and end locations
data_map = {
    # Hartsfield-Jackson Atlanta International Airport 
    # to
    # Aéroport de Paris-Charles de Gaulle
    "lat": [33.64, 49.01],
    "lon": [-84.44, 2.55],
}

layout_map = {
    # Chart title
    "title": "ATL to CDG",
    # Hide legend
    "showlegend": False,
    # Focus on relevant area
    "geo": {
        "resolution": 50,
        "showland": True,
        "showocean": True,
        "landcolor": "4a4",
        "oceancolor": "77d",
        "lataxis": {
            "range": [20, 60]
        },
        "lonaxis": {
            "range": [-100, 20]
        }
    }
}

# Flight displayed as a thick, red plot
line_map = {
    "width": 5,
    "color": "red"
}


page = """
# Getting started with Taipy GUI

My text: <|{text}|>

<|{text}|input|>

<|Run local|button|on_action=on_button_action|>

<|{data}|chart|x=x_col|y[1]=y_col1|y[2]=y_col1|>

<|{data_map}|chart|type=scattergeo|mode=lines|lat=lat|lon=lon|line={line_map}|layout={layout_map}|>

"""

def on_button_action(state):
    global is_first_time
    notify(state, 'info', f'The text is: {state.text}')
    state.text = "Button Pressed"
    if state.is_first_time == True:
        threading.Thread(target=update_list(state), daemon=True).start()
        state.is_first_time = False

def on_change(state, var_name, var_value):
    if var_name == "text" and var_value == "Reset":
        state.text = ""
        return

def update_list(state):
    i = 0
    while True:
        i += 1
        list_to_display.append(0)
        list_to_display.pop(0)
        state.list_to_display_1 = list_to_display
        data_1 = data
        data_1["x_col"].append(7)
        data_1["y_col1"].append(2)
        state.data = data_1
        data_map_1 = data_map
        data_map_1["lat"][1] += 1
        state.data_map = data_map_1
        time.sleep(2)

Gui(page=page).run(dark_mode=False,port=5002, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Comment: The line `if state.is_first_time == True:` can be reduced to `if state.is_first_time:` because the value already returns a boolean expression.

Answer (score 0):

Taipy does not natively support streaming. What you have done would be how to refresh a chart. I would suggest using [long_callbacks](https://docs.taipy.io/en/latest/manuals/gui/callbacks/#task-progress) to have this same behavior with less coding.

It is possible to add streaming to our roadmap so that Taipy supports it natively if this is a need.

Answer (score 0):

I’m attempting to implement something similar where I’m reading data from a CAN bus and want to update live values and charts on taipy. Streaming would be awesome but for now will try the o.p solution or long callbacks.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).